# Swiss 721 Web Font issue

Tags: fonts, webfonts

I am using the web font Swiss 721 for a project I am doing, but on certain letters it seems to come out pixelated or blurred, I have attached a screen shot so you can see. I am just wondering if anyone else has had this issue with Swiss or any other font when using it for web? As my initial Photoshop front end stuff all looked sharp.[image: Screenshot Swiis Web Font]

Comment: you're going to have to rephrase your question to something that makes sense for Stackoverflow, which is for questions around "I have the following code, but it doesn't work because I expect this:... but I see this: ... and I don't understand why after searching the web for clues or answers". Right now you're asking "has someone else seen this?" the answer to which is not meaningful (even if anyone says yes, that doesn't help solve any problems)

Comment: I have attached an image @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans to show you the pixelation on the font??

Comment: Right, but that is not "a programming problem", and simply knowing that other people get this too won't solve a programming problem. It might put your mind at ease, but: why? Simply knowing that at least one other person also has this happen doesn't bring anyone any closer to an actual "why this happens" and "how to fix it", so: are you asking how to get the font to render crisply? If so, change your phrasing to that, and show the code you're currently using, and mention the browsers you see this happening in, so that people can help solve an actual problem.

Comment: sorry @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I thought I worded it okay tbh. I just wanted to see if anyone had the same problem and if so had found some sort of solution to it. I didnt think in that much depth about the wording, I am new to the site.

Comment: unfortunately, if that's really all you wanted to know, then I have to point out that this is [entirely not what Stackoverflow is for](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You will have more luck getting an answer on some of the stackexchange boards like [superuser.com](http://superuser.com), or a type-dedicated board (like typophile, although as I write this, that's down for maintenance). SO questions are supposed to help solve problems, or clarify complex issues, so that users beyond just the one asking will benefit from the answer. That is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt to minimise the visual damage with the following global level CSS:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
font-smooth: always;
```

This is a good starting block in Chrome and Firefox but doesn't help with the bolder versions so in your @font-face declaration you will also need to ensure that the font-weights are correct per font family.

Swiss 721 really doesn't accept in-browser weighting to the font well so you will have to override any tags like strong, b etc with the relevant stronger version in your CSS rather than relying on the browser to apply it.

You can also try serving the TTF over the other variants to your specific element as the weightings appear to be different when using this format. Note that TTF won't serve in IE, so gracefully fallback if you use this method.